# Update Header String when looping through an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, replace

**Background:** I am looping through database data and outputing it to the page in a table. My loop outputs the header information first but the headers are what I would call NOT front-end ready.

**For example:** child_0_birthday needs to be changed to Child 1 Birthday.

**So far what I have is below:**

```
    //Define table header section here
        foreach ($fields as $k => $v){
        $html .= '<th class="manage-column" data-key="'.esc_html($v).'">'.updateHeaderName(vsz_cf7_admin_get_field_name($v)) .'</th>';
                                    }

    //This function would do the clean up

    $devHeaderNames = array("child_0_birthday", "child_0_fname", "child_0_lname", "child_0_age");

function updateHeaderName($oldHeader) {

    if (in_array($oldHeader, $devHeaderNames))
      {
     //This is where I would want to change the value of $oldHeader to something cleaner and spit it back out. I could write a very long if statement but there has to be a better way. 
        if ($oldHeader == child_0_fname){
            $newHeader = "Child 1 First Name";
            return $newHeader;
        }else if...
      }
   }
```

**QUESTION:** Is there a more efficient way then writing a very long if statement to change the string that is show in the header for each column?

Comment: Create a replacement array and then http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: String replacement should work. Alternatively, you can explode your variable name on ``_`` and create a lookup table that replaces backend variable names with more user-friendly ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use your array to translate associating the key and value.  Assuming `$header = "child_0_birthday"`:

```
$devHeaderNames = array("child_0_birthday" => "Child 1 Birthday"); //etc...

if(isset($devHeaderNames[$header])) {
    $header = $devHeaderNames[$header];
}
```

Comment: I knew there would be an easier way. Thanks @AbraCadaver this make sense.